# IBM Connections and IBM Websphere Portal integration

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-connections

I'm integrating IBM Connections and IBM Websphere Portal using this guideline ([guideline page](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Fast%20Track%20Documentation%20for%20Version%208#action=openDocument&res_title=Integrating_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_with_IBM_Connections_Files_and_Profiles_V8&content=pdcontent)).

To deploy portal application archive SNPortlets.paa I need to know a couple of parameters from connections installation(network deployment installation) to run the script:

```
-DICportletWebapp=portletWebapp
-DICblogsHomepageHandle=homepagehandle
-DICemailSetting=emailSetting
-DICtagSearchType=tagSearchType
-DICdsxAdminId=
-DICdsxAdminPwd=
```

(those I've tried to figured out)

```
-DICbaseURL=https://connections_domain
-DICprofilesContextRoot=/profiles
-DICfilesContextRoot=/files
-DICprofilesURL=https://connections_domain/profiles
-DICprofilesURLunsecured=http://connections_domain/profiles
-DICsearchContextRoot=/search
-DICnewsContextRoot=/news 
-DICfilesURL=https://connections_domain/files
-DICsearchURL=https://connections_domain/search
-DICoauthURL=https://connections_domain/connections/oauth
-DICnewsURL=https://connections_domain/news
-DICoauthContextRoot=connections/oauth
```

The question: is there any config file or other source where can I get all those parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure they are generally included in your LotusConnections-config.xml it should be in your deployment manager.

for instance on my server it's located at... 
/local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/cells/localhostCell01/LotusConnections-config/LotusConnections-config.xml

```
    <sloc:serviceReference acf_config_file="acf-config-nf.xml" bootstrapHost="" bootstrapPort="" clusterName="conCluster" enabled="true" person_card_service_name_js_eval="generalrs.label_personcard_activitieslink" person_card_service_url_pattern="/service/html/mainpage#dashboard%2Cmyactivities%2Cuserid%3D{userid}%2Cname%3D{displayName}" serviceName="activities" ssl_enabled="true">
    <sloc:href>
        <sloc:hrefPathPrefix>/activities</sloc:hrefPathPrefix>
        <sloc:static href="http://con.ihost.com:81" ssl_href="**https://con.ihost.com:444**"/>
        <sloc:interService href="https://con.ihost.com:444"/>
    </sloc:href>
</sloc:serviceReference>
```

-DICblogsHomepageHandle     The Blogs home page handle for your IBM Connections deployment. The default is homepage.
-DICemailSetting    Set to email-exposed or email-hidden depending on whether the IBM Connections server is configured to expose user email addresses or to hide them.
-DICtagSearchType   Set to search or mysearch, depending on whether you want the tag cloud to display tags only for public content or tags for public content as well as for content the logged-in user contributed.
-DICdsxAdminId  The user ID that is set in the dsx-admin role for the Profiles and Communities services.
-DICdsxAdminPwd     The password for the dsx-admin user. 
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.5.1/doc/accessible/plugins/en_us/html-wrapper.html

basicaly dsx-admin you shouldn't have to use. 
tagSearchType and emailSettings are just flags

Comment: I should also mention that's just for activities, there are others much like it for other services such as forums, and I think oAuth

Comment: from _LotusConnections-config.xml_ I was able to get some of the parameters (that is the second code block in original message). But there is nothing about parameters from first code block like '-DICportletWebapp, -DICblogsHomepageHandle, -DICemailSetting, 
-DICtagSearchType, -DICdsxAdminId, -DICdsxAdminPwd'

Comment: dsxAdminId is the id you've assigned to the j2ee role for directory extensions... generally this is going to be your wasadmin user

Comment: thx, I will test dsxAdminId == wasadmin. Any ideas on other parameters?